# I am implementing focus listener to my suduku game but its not working

Tags: java

if user enter any alphabet in my suduku board it will not allow to go to other cells until he change that alphabet to digit.if he press tab also doesnot move .if he makes use of mouse also does not get into other cell until he changes that alphabet.also if alphabet enters a message want to display alphabets are not allowed.i my code the message displaying three time and repetdly .how to avoid this.i want to display message once untill user changes the alphabet and focus is on the current alphabet entered cell only.

Code:

```
private void setPuzzle(){   
            for(int row=0;row<size;row++){  
                for(int col=0;col<size;col++){  
                    cell[row][col]=new JTextField(3);   
                    cell[row][col].setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);   
                    cell[row][col].addFocusListener(this);
                    panel.add(cell[row][col]);  
                }   
            }   
        }   
  @Override
    public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
       // throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {   
       for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
           for(int j=0;j<size;j++){ 
               String value=(cell[i][j].getText()); 
               if(value.equals("")){    
                   cell[i][j].setBackground(Color.WHITE);   
               }    
               else if (!value.matches("[1-9]+")){  
                   cell[i][j].setBackground(Color.red);     
                   cell[i][j].requestFocus();
                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(getParent(),"Alphabetsare not allowed");  

               }    
           }    
       }    
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting the message-box for three times or continuously? I think it should be continuous.

Comment: how to terminate from that i am unable to do that.plz tell how to terminate

Comment: how are u running your program?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `e.getSource()` to get the cell that triggered the focus event.
Do the check on this cell only, this way the message will be displayed only once even if there are other cells that don't contain a numerical value.

Also, to be able to get the text from the cell you will have to cast the object returned by `e.getSource()` to `JTextField`. 
For exanple:
`JTextField cell = (JTextField) e.getSource()`

```
@Override
public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {   
   JTextField cell = (JTextField) e.getSource();
   String value = cell.getText();
   if(!value.matches("\\d+") && value.length() > 0){
      cell.setText("");
      cell.setBackground(Color.red);     
      cell.requestFocus();
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(getParent(),"Alphabetsare not allowed");
   }else{
      cell.setBackground(Color.WHITE);   
   }
}
```

Comment: after that how to check whether it is alphabet or number in that cell and how to set the focus and messgae untill user changes the alphabet

Comment: it is agin repeating.if i enter any alphabet in a cell it display a message alphabets are not allowed.but when i mouse click on  empty cell there appering red color and showing message two times

Comment: @REDDY I've edited my answer, now it displays the message only if the cell characters in it and those characters are not numbers.

Answer (score 0):

In the else condition where your are validating the numbers, you are requesting focus and then showing the message box. So it will obviously will trigger the lostFocus event.

Try swapping the code as:

```
else if (!value.matches("[1-9]+"))
{  
cell[i][j].setBackground(Color.red);     
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(getParent(),"Alphabetsare not allowed");
cell[i][j].requestFocus();  
}
```

Comment: i tried this also .same problem also encountering.i run like this i will set some puzzle then i will go to some cell and enter alphbaet and press tab yhen it shows alphabets not allowed repetedly.